# Parse JS multiple relation query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have 3 classes (Survey, SurveyItem, VoteSurvey)

- SurveyItem contain pointer to Survey
- VoteSurvey contain pointer to Survey and pointer to SurveyItem

i need to include all the surveys that i haven't voted for.

```js
  //survey
  var surveyQuery = new Parse.Query(Survey);
  surveyQuery.equalTo("condo",pointerCondo); //essential column filter

  //surveyitem
  var surveyItemQuery = new Parse.Query(SurveyItem);
  surveyItemQuery.matchesQuery("survey",surveyQuery);
  //all survey with filter & surveyitems (return ok)

  var voteQuery = new Parse.Query(VoteSurvey);
  //...
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your class structure and fields are, so their might be a better way to do this. But, how about querying for all the surveys you have voted for and then finding all surveys that don't match? For example:

```
var voteQuery = new Parse.Query('VoteSurvey');
voteQuery.equalTo('user', user);
voteQuery.find().then(function(results) {
  var alreadyVotedSurveyIds = [];

  for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
    alreadyVotedSurveyIds.push(results[i].get('survey').id);
  }

  var surveyQuery = new Parse.Query('Survey');
  surveyQuery.notContainedIn('objectId', alreadyVotedSurveyIds);
  return surveyQuery.find();
}).then(function(notVotedSurveys) {
  // notVotedSurveys is the array of surveys not voted for
});
```

*Note: keep in mind that Parse query has a default limit of 100.*